# MiniMax Recursive Algorithm (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am pretty new so I apologize if I make any errors in posting here... I did a search but didn't come up with much that would help me. I am writing a miniMax algorithm for a variation on Tic Tac Toe. This variation allows either player to put an X or an O anywhere on the board. I am having trouble with the recursion and was hoping I could get a bit of guidance.

```
class TicTacToeBoard:

def __init__(self, initGameBoard):
    #initGameBoard is a string
    self.board = initGameBoard

def getEmptySpaces(self):
    return self.board.count("-")

def markX(self, index):
    self.board = self.board[:index] + "x" + self.board[index+1:]

def markO(self, index):
    self.board = self.board[:index] + "o" + self.board[index+1:]

def endGame(self):
    #determines if someone has won 
    endGameStates = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
    for x in range(len(endGameStates)):
        trySlice = self.board[endGameStates[x][0]] + self.board[endGameStates[x][1]] + \
                   self.board[endGameStates[x][2]]
        if trySlice[0] == trySlice[1] == trySlice[2] and "-" not in trySlice:
            return True
    return False

def draw(self):
    #determines if there has been a draw 
    if "-" not in self.board:
        endGameStates = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
        for x in range(len(endGameStates)):
            trySlice = self.board[endGameStates[x][0]] + self.board[endGameStates[x][1]] + \
                       self.board[endGameStates[x][2]]
            if trySlice[0] == trySlice[1] == trySlice[2] and "-" not in trySlice:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

def __str__(self):
    boardStr = ""
    for char in self.board:
        boardStr += char
    return boardStr
```

Above is my board class. I'm just using strings, not doing anything too fancy. I'm also using a very simple Node class that just stores data (though I suppose I might be able to just use strings too I guess...)

```
from tic_tac_toe_board import TicTacToeBoard      
from node import Node

nodeQueue = []

def fitnessFunction(gameBoard):
    #only runs if end game or if all full
    if gameBoard.draw():
        return 0
    else:
        emptySpaces = gameBoard.getEmptySpaces()
        if emptySpaces %2 == 0:
            #max won
            return (emptySpaces + 1) *1
        else:
            #max lost
            return (emptySpaces + 1) *-1

def miniMax(gameBoard):
    if gameBoard.endGame() or if "-" not in gameBoard:
        #end game checks for winner, second clause checks for full/draw
        return fitnessFunction(gameBoard)
    else:
        emptyIndexes = [] #keeps track of which indexes are empty
        count = 0
        for char in gameBoard:
            if char == "-":
                emptyIndexes.append(count)
            count +=1             
        if len(emptyIndexes) %2 != 0:
            #max's turn
            for index in emptyIndexes:
                childNode = Node(gameBoard.markX(index))
                nodeQueue.append(childNode)
                childNode = Node(gameBoard.markO(index))
                nodeQueue.append(childNode)
        return miniMax()
```

The fitnessFunction returns a score based on the number of empty spaces left. I'm having trouble with my recursive miniMax method. What I need to do is check for the base cases (either player winning, or a draw) and if those base cases are not true, I figure out whose move it is based on the number of empty spaces left. I think I've gotten that far, but I don't know what to do next (the recursive part). I also need to be able to get the min or max of children, depending on whose turn it is. I guess I am lost with the recursion. I'm new to CS and haven't touched much on it. Any hints would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Not sure i understand the question. After you know whose move it is, what do you want to do?

Comment: If it is max's turn, the max of its children will be returned. If it's min's turn, the min will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a mini-max algorithm, you don't need an example upon which to apply it. Most games require a mini-max algorithm.

So if you want one, decide how it must behave. Then write a test for at least one example of that behavior.

Post your test. (Not a game, but just a test of the data that would result from a game.)

If your algorithm does not work, your game program can't work.

Hint: A mini-max algorithm depends only upon the evaluations of game paths, not upon the game being played.